# using jekyll pagination to display a custom categories

Tags: pagination, jekyll, permalinks, jekyll-paginator

as far as jekyll pagination doesn't work with permalink I make my root index page display the `blog posts` like blog page ,
my website have a blog / questions / news / media - posts categories

so before I use the pagination it was pretty nice I was able to display specified posts in specified place with

```
{% for posts in site.categories['blog'] %}
```

in /blog.html to display `blog posts` only in /blog/ with permalink of course

now I move the code of blog.html to the index.html page,
and pagination works fine but display all posts `blog` `media` `news`

so there's any help ? or some tricks I can use to make the blog posts in multi pages with/without pagination ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also tried to build my page with `jekyll-paginate` but as the plugin is no longer under active development, i switched to [octopress-paginate](https://github.com/octopress/paginate).

This allows us you use a simple syntax like:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
```

or any other collection / page-type you have.